# Mapper Reuse Mappstruct

Tags: java

friends how can I reuse a mapper inside another mapper

my code is

```html
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ProductoToRepositoryMapper {

  ProductoToRepositoryMapper INSTANCE = Mappers
      .getMapper(ProductoToRepositoryMapper.class);


  @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
  @Mapping(source = "convenioResponse.id", target = "id")
  @Mapping(source = "convenioResponse.cantidad", target = "cantidad)
  ProductoRepositoryEntity map(ConvenioResponse convenioResponse);
```

```html
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface OtherToRepositoryMapper {


  @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
  @Mapping(source = "convenioResponse.id", target = "id")
  @Mapping(source = "convenioResponse.cantidad", target = "cantidad)
  ProductoRepositoryEntity map(OtherClass otherClass);



}
```

how can i reuse the other mapper , any suggestion

Grazie in anticipo

Comment: You can create an instance variable in OtherToRepositoryMapper  for ProductoToRepositoryMapper mapper = ProductoToRepositoryMapper.INSTANCE and just use it in.

Comment: but the instance variable accepts only the ResponseConvention object and I want to pass it to another class that is not this one but has the same fields, will it work?